# Images in list, smartest way to do this?

Tags: html, css

I realise that asking for 'the smartest way' is a little vague, but this seems to be part of my problem. When coding with HTML/CSS (And many other languages, I imagine) there are so many ways to achieve 1 thing. **But how do I know what works best for my situation?**

For example, currently I am trying to create two lists, that each have a (different!) image in front of the list item. See image for example.

[image]

I can go about this many ways, but I came up with three that seemed most suitable:

1. Create a container div holding two unordered lists. In these UL's, put list items. Give every list item a different class so I can give them the image through css with ::before.
2. Create a container div holding two unordered lists. In these UL's, put a table with one row and two columns, one holding the image and the other holding the text.
3. Create a container div holding two unordered lists. In these UL's, put two div's, one holding the image and the other holding the text.

In all cases I would use CSS for styling and media queries for scaling.

**Which one should I choose, and why?**

Comment: Check my update answer if issue is still alive..

Answer (score 1):

I think that the more fancy solution is create a container `div` holding two unordered lists and next for each `li` tag add `display: inline-flex` in css (then you can easily handle two elements next to each other).

And also you can add do main container `div`

```
display: flex;
flex-flow: row;
```

then your unordered lists will be next to each other.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flex` for the same.

```css
.twoBox {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.firstBox,
.secondBox {
  flex: 1 1 0;
}

.leading {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 2;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.name_circle {
  flex: 1 1 0;
  align-self: center;
}

.color_circle {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #3e9cc0;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.color_circle_detail {
  line-height: 1.5;
  flex: 10 0 0;
  /* You can put here value as your need */
}

.color_circle_detail h4 {
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #505050;
  padding: 0;
}

.color_circle_detail p {
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<div class="twoBox">
  <div class="firstBox">
    <div class="leading">
      <div class="name_circle">
        <div class="color_circle">
          H
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="color_circle_detail">
        <h4>Sender</h4>
        <p>Subject</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
          irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="secondBox">
    <div class="leading">
      <div class="name_circle">
        <div class="color_circle">
          H
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="color_circle_detail">
        <h4>Sender</h4>
        <p>Subject</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
          irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If I use Flex, all my list items will be displayed horizontally, but I need 4 columns (or 2 per UL). How do define in how many columns it flexes?

Comment: You check my updated answer ? I have posted the same i think ? if no, please make an image just like as you want.

Comment: Yes I have seen it, but if I add more columns to your example, it will just give me more horizontal columns. I wants more rows, not more columns.

Comment: make a fiddle with my example as you commented only  " if I add more columns to your example, it will just give me more horizontal columns." section

Answer (score 0):

Your first idea is the best in my opinion. But I would tweak it with `<img>` tags instead of using css to set your images. This has the advantage of being SEO friendly, mostly if you add `alt` attributes to your images.

See this snippet for sample:

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

ul {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 40px;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

img {
  width: 50px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

p {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consecuetur a lit.
      </p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consecuetur a lit.
      </p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consecuetur a lit.
      </p>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consecuetur a lit.
      </p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consecuetur a lit.
      </p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consecuetur a lit.
      </p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```